# Convert Mysql Database into Json

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database, I want to change it to json format with results like the one below

```
["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
```

but when I made the code using PHP as below

```
<?php
require_once("../con.php");

$list = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE reff='admin'");
$r = array();
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($list)) {
    $r[] = array($data['username']);
}
echo json_encode($r, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

the results are different from what I want, the following results

```
[ [ "aaa" ], [ "bbb" ], [ "ccc" ] ]
```

is there any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: Just replace this line `$r[] = array($data['username']);` with this one `$r[] = $data['username'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do is  `$r[] = $data['username'];` instead of `$r[] = array($data['username']);` because with this line `$r[] = array($data['username']);` you are trying to push username as an **array** not a username **string** value every time on your `$r` that's why it creates extra brackets `[]` surrounding your username value.

but if you don't want to change your existing code then you can use this to get result as expected with this extra line of code `$r = array_merge(...$r)`, here `...`  known as the splat operator

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an array to another array. see this attached change:

```
<?php
require_once("../con.php");

$list = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE reff='admin'");
$r = [];
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($list)) {
    $r[] = $data['username'];
}
echo json_encode($r, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

Replace $r[] = array($data['username']);

To $r[] = $data['username'];

2.

```
"SELECT username FROM user WHERE reff='admin'" // * -> username 
// in while
$r[] = $data[0];
or
$r[] = current($data);
```

3.format in sql

```
SELECT CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT('"',username,'"'),']') FROM user WHERE reff='admin'
```

see. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192208/mysql-return-json-from-a-standard-sql-query

4. if your mysql v5.7.22+

use function JSON_ARRAY、JSON_OBJECT、JSON_QUOTE in sql
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html